# Why are any of the inputs I provide to argparse set as unrecognized arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Goal: Create Simple Pipreqs to Generate requirements file script

I'm already handling installing pipreqs and checking if a package exists in another file. That's not the problem.
I already have read: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action

Yet every time I run this script it says "unrecognized arguments or ignored explicit argument".

```
import argparse
import subprocess

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-q", "--set_req", action="store_false", required=False)
parser.add_argument("-d", "--directory", action="store_const", const=".", required=False)

def use_pipreqs_to_generate_requirements(dir_name):
    subprocess.check_call(['pipreqs', f'{dir_name}'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    print(f"Req: {args.set_req}")

    print(f" Dir {args.directory}")
    # use_pipreqs_to_generate_requirements(args.directory)
```

I run it with `python3 setup_requirements_argparse.py --set_req True -d "."`.

I have varied the value after `-q` or `--set-req` to `true`, `True`, `False`, `false`.

When I write those flags with = signs, I get the error "ignored explicit argument":

```
python3 setup_requirements_argparse.py --set_req=True -d="test/"
usage: setup_requirements_argparse.py [-h] [-q] [-d]
setup_requirements_argparse.py: error: argument -q/--set_req: ignored explicit argument 'True'
```

I have also set the `args =` outside of the main function to see if that fixes it, it doesn't.

---

Solution For Future Wanderers:

A reference to answer in the linked question:
"A `store_true` argument in argparse indicates that the very presence of the option will automatically store `True` in the corresponding variable." - Jordan Lewis.

This part of the documentation says [ArgparseAction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)

Action
`store_true` and `store_false` - These are special cases of 'store_const' used for storing the values True and False respectively. In addition, they create default values of False and True respectively.

To clarify this point, the usage of these argument (store_false or store_true) **does not accept input**. When you set action to `store_true` or `store_false` then including the flag that uses that will perform what you have in the action value which means storing false or true in that argument flag. *The absence of the flag will use either your default value if you've set one or the opposite value of what you've asked it to store.*

Changing my solution to store_true and store arrives at the behavior I wish to see. Simply including the -q flag will perform the requirements.txt generation I desire.

```
parser.add_argument("-q", "--set_req", action="store_true", required=False)
parser.add_argument("-d", "--directory", action="store", default=".", required=False)
...
if args.set_req:
    use_pipreqs_to_generate_requirements(args.directory)
```

Comment: ```--set-req``` by existence in your arguments is already defined as ```False``` The absence of it means it is True.

Comment: 'store_true', 'store_false', 'store_const' don't take arguments, even with '='.  Values are set by defined `default` and `const`.  The docs should be clear about this.  You may experiement with the default 'store', and a `nargs='?'`.  Set `default` and `const` as well, and track the results.

Comment: Take the exmples seriously.  Neither is a way of entering in a `True/False` value or '.'.  You have some unstated assumption about how argparse should respond to arguments like this.

Comment: Usage is up to 2 flag strings, neither takes an additional value. `setup_requirements_argparse.py [-h] [-q] [-d]`

Comment: The docs are not clear on this, obvious from other people also having the same issue, you don't have to be rude about it. Thank you for your response nonetheless.